# Flatten Data By ID

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data table that looks like this (note this is condensed, there are some ID with 2+ TIMEs):

```
ID        TIME
1         10:12
1         4:43
2         9:12
3         1:43
3         16:47
4         2:55
```

I would like to flatten it so it looks like this:

```
ID  Time_1    Time_2
1     10:12    4:43
2     4:43
3     1:43     16:47
4     2:55
```

I'm reviewing 'flattening' options but have not yet found the correct answer.

https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.14.1/generated/pandas.Index.flatten.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To format to exactly the required layout, you can use [`.pivot()`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.pivot.html) as follows:

```
(df.assign(serial='Time_'+df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
   .pivot(index='ID', columns='serial', values='TIME')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
   ID Time_1 Time_2
0   1  10:12   4:43
1   2   9:12    NaN
2   3   1:43  16:47
3   4   2:55    NaN
```

If you want the missing values to show as blank, you can use:

```
(df.assign(serial='Time_'+df.groupby('ID').cumcount().add(1).astype(str))
   .pivot(index='ID', columns='serial', values='TIME').fillna('')
   .rename_axis(columns=None)
   .reset_index()
)
```

**Result:**

```
   ID Time_1 Time_2
0   1  10:12   4:43
1   2   9:12       
2   3   1:43  16:47
3   4   2:55
```

Answer (score 4):

Try to groupby and join your strings

```
new = df.groupby('ID')['TIME'].agg(' '.join).str.split(expand=True)
new.columns = [f'Time_{col+1}' for col in new.columns] # rename columns

   Time_1 Time_2
ID              
1   10:12   4:43
2    9:12   None
3    1:43  16:47
4    2:55   None
```